# Assembly code/AVX instructions for multiplication of complex numbers. (GCC inline assembly)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, complex-numbers, avx

We're running a scientific program and we would like to implement AVX features. The whole program (written in Fortran+C) is going to be vectorized and at the moment I'm trying to implement complex number multiplication within GCC inline assembly.

The assembly code takes 4 complex numbers and performs two complex multiplications at once:

```
v2complex cmult(v2complex *a, v2complex *b) {
    v2complex ret;
    asm (
        "vmovupd %2,%%ymm1;"
        "vmovupd %2, %%ymm2;"
        "vmovddup %%ymm2, %%ymm2;"
        "vshufpd $15,%%ymm1,%%ymm1,%%ymm1;"
        "vmulpd %1, %%ymm2, %%ymm2;"
        "vmulpd %1, %%ymm1, %%ymm1;"
        "vshufpd $5,%%ymm1,%%ymm1, %%ymm1;"
        "vaddsubpd %%ymm1, %%ymm2,%%ymm1;"
        "vmovupd %%ymm1, %0;"
        :
        "=m"(ret)
        :
        "m" (*a),
        "m" (*b)
        );
    return ret;
}
```

where a and b are 256-bit double precision:

```
typedef union v2complex {
    __m256d v;
    complex c[2];
} v2complex;
```

The problem is that that the code mostly produces the correct result, but sometimes it fails.

I am very new to assembly, but I tried to figure it out by myself. It seems that the C program (optimized -O3) interacts with the registers `ymm` used in the assembly code. For instance, I can printf one of the values (e.g. a) before executing the multiplication and the program does never give wrong results.

My question is how to tell GCC not to interact with ymm. I did not manage to
put the `ymm` to clobbered registers list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you surmise, the problem is that you haven’t told GCC which registers you are clobbering.  I’m surprised if they don’t yet support putting YMM registers in the clobber list; what version of GCC are you using?

In any event, it will almost certainly suffice to put the corresponding XMM registers in the clobber list instead:

```
: "=m" (ret) : "m" (*a), "m" (*b) : "%xmm1", "%xmm2");
```

---

Some other notes:

- You’re loading both inputs twice, which is inefficient.  There’s no reason to do that.
- I would use `"r" (a), "r" (b)` as constraints and write my loads like `vmovupd (%2), %%ymm1`.  Probably no difference in the generated code, but it seems more idiomatically correct.
- Don’t forget to put a `vzeroupper` following AVX code before any SSE code is executed to avoid (large) stalls.

Comment: thank you very much, that solved the problem =). I'm using gcc 4.7.2 and thx for your advice.

Comment: Don't use `“r” (a), “r” (b)` with `vmovupd (%2), %%ymm1` etc, GCC will assume that *a and *b aren't accessed (unless you add a "memory" clobber).

Answer (score 3):

I add two comments, not directly answering your question:

- I strongly suggest using compiler intrinsics instead of direct assembly. This way the compiler takes care of the register allocation and can do better job at optimizing your code (inline methods, reorder instructions, etc.)
- [Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/) has a [C++ vector class library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/vectorclass.pdf) of optimized vectorized operations, including operations on complex numbers. Even if you might not be able to use his libraries directly in your C code, his optimized code might be a good starting point; see `src/special/complexvec.h` in [the zipped source code](http://www.agner.org/optimize/vectorclass.zip).

Comment: Thx, I'll have a look at it even though I will not be able to use it. Actually, I had compiled both versions, the intrinsic code and assembly, and i wanted to know why assembly did not run well since both compiled to the same optimized assembly code (objdump -S ..).

Comment: But intrinsics also have disadvantages:  The compiler takes care of register allocation and reorders instructions, etc.  It is not generally true that a compiler does this better.